# How to get the Time->epoch to be from a certain timezone

Tags: perl

We are trying to use utime to update files to a certain timestamp.   To do this we are taking the string version of the timestamp, turning it into a "time object" and then using the epoch method to get the epoch to update the time file.

```
my $yyyymmddhhmmss;  # variable holding string version of time. example: 20150512:150632    
my $fileTime = Time::Piece->strptime($yyyymmddhhmmss, '%Y%m%d:%H%M%S'); 
utime $fileTime->epoch, $fileTime->epoch, $outfile;
```

However, it is setting the file timestamp to UTC, which is different than the time zone we are in.   Besides manually adding the extra seconds, is there another way to have the epoch push out the seconds for our time zone?

Comment: Epoch time is always in UTC [by definition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

Comment: Sorry, let me phrase it a different way, can we get the number of seconds from Jan, 1st, 1970 for our datetime in our timezone?

Comment: You want `localtime->strptime(...)` if `$yyyymmddhhmmss` holds a local timestamp.

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot  Yep, just tried that out, it worked.   If you want to put that as answer, I'll mark it as such.   Thanks for your help!

Comment: @ThisSuitIsBlackNot: Please scribe an answer. I think this is a valuable lesson.

Comment: The number of seconds since 1970-01-01 00:00:00 *local time* is not likely to be a useful quantity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nowhere do you specify that `$yyyymmddhhmmss` is a localtime.

Replace

```
Time::Piece->strptime($yyyymmddhhmmss, '%Y%m%d:%H%M%S')
```

with

```
localtime->strptime($yyyymmddhhmmss, '%Y%m%d:%H%M%S')
```